# Object function returns function instead of value

Tags: javascript

I have a really rookie question....

If I define a JS object, and I use a function to generate a property value, why does the property value return a function instead of the generated value?

Example:

```
var object = {
  bla: 1,
  days: [],
  test : function(){
    return 'bla';
  }
}

console.log(object.test);
```

I would expect `object.test` to be 'bla'. Instead it's `function(){ return 'bla'; }`... Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to execute that function, in this way: `console.log(object.test());`
or, as pointed out by @YuriiKovalenko, you can write the function like this:

```
var object = {
  bla: 1,
  days: [],
  test : (function(){ return 'bla'; })()
}
```

and then `console.log(object.test);` will give you "bla"

Comment: Ok, great. And how can I rewrite it so that object.test will become 'bla'? Like, is it possible to automatically execute the function when looking up the value?

Comment: if you want that, you could simply write: `object.test = "bla"`, so when you access it like `object.test` it will return its value ("bla")

Comment: @Henk , `(function(){
    return 'bla';
  })()`

Answer (score 1):

Cause you set the value of object.test as a function in

```
var object = {
  bla: 1,
  days: [],
  test : function(){
    return 'bla';
  }
}
```

if you want to do so you have to get the value you have to execute `object.test()`